# Can't save List<T> class member

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, model

I am trying to save an appointment with a list of invitees.
The appointment saves well, but saving the invitees does not work.

This is what I've got:

Model for Appointment:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using ArrangeAppointments.Interfaces;

namespace ArrangeAppointments.Models
{
    public class Appointment : IAppointment
    {
        #region Implementation of IAppointments
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public int UserId { get; set; }
            public string Title { get; set; }
            public string Description { get; set; }
            public string Duration { get; set; }
            public List<Invitee> Invitees { get; set; }
        #endregion

        public void Save()
        {
            int appID = 0;
            using (var db = new MainDbContext())
            {
                var appointment = db.Appointments.Create();
                appointment.UserId = 1;
                appointment.Title = Title;
                appointment.Description = Description;
                appointment.Duration = Duration;
                db.Appointments.Add(appointment);
                int newId = db.SaveChanges();
                appID = appointment.Id;
            }
            SaveInvitees(appID);
        }

        public bool SaveInvitees(int appId)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (var invitee in Invitees)
                {
                    //invitee.Appointment_Id = appId;
                    invitee.Save(appId);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(e.InnerException);
                return false;
            }
            return true;

        }
    }
}
```

Model for Invitee:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using ArrangeAppointments.Interfaces;

namespace ArrangeAppointments.Models
{
    public class Invitee : IInvitee
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        //public int Appointment_Id { get; private set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Presence { get; set; }

        public void Save(int appId)
        {
            using (var db = new MainDbContext())
            {
                var invitee = db.Invitees.Create();
                invitee.Email = Email;
                invitee.Presence = Presence;
                db.Invitees.Add(invitee);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

The Invitees table also includes a field with the Id of the appointment to link each record to an appointment.
When I check the `innerException` in the debugger than I see that there is an error due to a `NullReference` Error.
This error is caused by a field called Appointment_Id that is automatically added to the internal db.Invitees SQL.

When I uncomment the Appointment_Id in the Invitee class than an `'Unknown column Appoinment_Id1'` error appears.

How can I get the value of `Appointment.Id` in the `invitee.appointment_Id`?

Answer (score 0):

> When I uncomment the Appointment_Id in the Invitee class than an 'Unknown column Appoinment_Id1' error appears.

From this line, I would say that there is something wrong in your model. From looking in your model... I would say that You are missing

```
public Appointment Appointment { get; set; }
```

in your Invitee class.

You can read up more on the topic: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

UPDATE 1
I would also advise you to use same DbContext for saving both entities. Or at the least think about using TransactionScope to make sure all this gets save in one transaction.
Also maybe think if you should be calling SaveChanges() inside the for loop.